# How to export CSV to Db with headers in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, csv

How to export csv to db in C#. It works fine when you have a plain text simple text. But in my case I need to parse headers as single row.

[image: Here is the Screen shot of CSV which i want to export]

Comment: you want it dynamic create table and export or static?

Comment: The screenshot is from a table not from CSV. CSV is a simple text file so please copy/paste the text from the file instead of an image

Comment: No its a text from Csv

Comment: @ShahroozAnsari Any of it but i want the headers (AirArabia(text)) with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options!

- use some driver custom functions (depends on your database)
- use a [schema.ini](
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver)
- do it manually ...

Comment: There are some nugets out there https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=csv which will follow the (unofficial) standard described in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: I have Tried CSVReader with Datatables but i am confused in how to get a plain text of row, in csv, As csv have only columns and rows format

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually with `while` iteration. Before using loop, you should read csv file from path with StreamReader.

For example:

```
using(var csvReader = new StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead("your file path")))
{
     while (!csvReader.EndOfStream)
     {
          var rows = csvReader.ReadLine();
          var columns = rows.Split(';');

          if(values.Length > 1)
          {
               // Your logic getting values to save db
          }
     }
}
```